# Why is hyperxmp suppressing the PDf Info dictionary?

Tags: hyperref, pdf, metadata, hyperxmp

The following source generates in the log file the following:

```
Package hyperxmp Warning: Suppressing the _entire_ PDF Info dictionary.
(hyperxmp)                Please notify the hyperxmp maintainer.
....
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 21.
<<sRGB.icc>>

!! new-hyperxmp--generic packet command used!!
```

When I examine Properties of the resulting pdf file with Adobe Acrobat, I do see the title and author that I supplied to the `\hypersetup` command.

So what is going on with `hyperxmp`?

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DocumentMetadata{uncompress,pdfstandard=a-2u}

\documentclass{memoir}

\RequirePackage{hyperxmp} % to add metadata info into pdf
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  unicode,
  pdfapart=2, pdfaconformance=u,
  colorlinks, citecolor=red, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue,
  pdftitle={The Book},
  pdfauthor={Somebody Who},pdfcreator={Somebody Ese},
  pdfpublisher={The Author},
  pdfdate={\today},
  pdflang={en},pdfmetalang={en},
  pdfpubtype={Book},
  pdfproducer=pdfTeX-1.40.23, %why needed ????????????
}

\begin{document}
Hello!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ignore it. The pdfmanagement has to patch hyperxmp currently and that leads to this warning.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Ok, thanks! (Needless to say, when I first see a warning in the log, I have to investigate!)